# React - Mutating form object for each change . Is that anyway we can do it in a better way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleChange(evt, field) {
    let form = this.state.form;
    form[field] = evt.value;
    console.log('change triggered');
    this.setState({
      form: form
    });
  }

render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
          text={this.state.form.name}
          onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, 'name'); }} />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
          text={this.state.form.email}
          onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, 'email'); }}        />        
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have added simple form for reference . In the above content Whenever form field changes handleChange method invoked and In that form object mutated updated as per field changes and setting to state object.

I want to know whether we can avoid mutation of object of each field text changes or Is there any other better way to address the same . Also want to know object mutation affects the performance in any way because here I mentioned couple of fields and In my original project I am working contains atleast 15 to 20 fields for each form.

Added the same working module.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssgcnu?file=Hello.js

Please help me out . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to update each character change you can use `onBlur` event.

```
 onBlur={event => { this.handleChange(event, 'name'); }}
```

So that on leaving the field only you can update the state.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Nice to have a new thought which i didn't think of and I want to know if user clicks before coming out of the field will the state updated or we need to update manually . Also In this also we are mutating object , I want to know is there any way we can do without mutate it. Your answer will reduce the mutation .

Comment: yeah then also it will trigger functions no worries, if you are going to click on buttton means you are going out of the field so no worry, it should work

Answer (score 1):

'...' Spread operator produces a shallow copy of an object

```
handleChange(evt, field) { 
let form = {...this.state.form};  //object spread notation
form[field] = evt.value;
console.log('change triggered'); 
this.setState({ form: form });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to forms with React, there are two approaches.

1) Uncontrolled components, which basically making use of refs and getting values from the DOM (please check the official documentation for more details https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) or

2) Controlled components making use of states and getting/handling values from React states (please check the official documentation for more details https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

With controlled components => React, state is the single source of truth (as official document suggests), that means, you need to provide methods to handle state changes as user provides the input

With uncontrolled components => Instead of updating state on every single change, you can get values inside of onSubmit method and handle them before submit. Since you won't need to update the state, you won't need additional functions to handle state changes.

For you seeking of better way to handling things and avoid mutations, it actually depends on your use case, but official documentation suggests that

> In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement
>   forms. In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React
>   component

When it comes to mutating object, indeed mutations is not good, but there are ways to avoid mutations during state changes. as @mhkit already suggested, you can use spread operator to create a new object (shallow copy, that means it only copies the values) or you could use `Object.assign()` method.

Let's say you have the following state

```
state = {
 form: {
  email: '',
  name: '',
  lastName: '',
  }
}
```

When you user provides the email, you basically need to update the email field,
in that case in your handleChangeEmail() method, what you can do is the following

```
this.handleChangeEmail = (value) => { 
this.setState(({form}) => {
   return {
     form: {
      ...form,
     email: value 
    }
})
}
```

So with this method, what I basically do is,
1) I utilize functional setState and extracted the current value of form via ES6 object destructuring, then I say that, okay my new form object inside of the state, will have all the existing field that former form has, BUT, the email field will have a new value based on the new input user provided.

By this way, instead of mutating form object, we created a shallow copy of it with some values are exactly the same, but some values are updated. THUS we prevent the mutation